# How can i solved eslint warning -- 'component' is declared but its value is never read -- when i am actually using the component

Tags: reactjs, next.js, eslint

I am getting this weird error of 'sellerDetails' is declared but its value is never read yet in the file I am calling the component. I am using it. I started getting this error a day just one day ago and now even I import the component it is not being rendered in the dom. so I fail to understand why I am getting the warning yet I have used the component. The worst this is that the component is not being rendered in the dom.  Below is my code.

I have also attached a screenshot of the code so that you see the warning that eslint is showing me.

```
import React from 'react';
import Grid from '@material-ui/core/Grid';
import Container from '@material-ui/core/Container';
import sellerDetails from './sellerDetails.Component';

const SingleAd = () => (
  <Container maxWidth='lg'>
    <Grid container spacing={1}>
      <Grid item container xs={12} sm={8} spacing={2}>
        <Grid item>
          Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Blanditiis
          illo earum minima. Nulla nam eligendi sequi illo voluptas doloremque
          consequuntur, enim accusantium itaque quod nihil quis sed animi
          officiis repellendus.
        </Grid>
      </Grid>
      <Grid item container xs={12} sm={4} spacing={2}>
        <Grid item>
          <sellerDetails />
        </Grid>
      </Grid>
    </Grid>
  </Container>
);
export default SingleAd;
```

from the attached image I hope you can see that the sellerDetails is faint meaning It is not being used yet I have used it in my code
[image: screenshot of my code]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]change your component name to `SellerDetails` and warning will be resolved. component name should be starting with capital letter

Comment: Thanks, soo much I just forgot a fundamental react.js rule, and thanks for reminding me